# Conditionally make a @property strong or weak

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, properties, objective-c-runtime

I am downloading a list of objects from an API to display to a user.  The list has a mix of two types of objects.  Imagine that they are combined books and authors, and the class definitions look like this:

```
@interface Book : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, strong) Author *author;

@end

@interface Author : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *fullName;
@property (nonatomic, weak) Book *book;

@end
```

Every `Book` can download its `Author` information from the API, and vice versa.

If the API gives me a `Book`, I can set its `author` property once I download it.  The `Author` object points back to the `Book` through the `book` property, but this doesn't create an [ARC Retain Cycle](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004447-1000810) because the `book` property is `weak`.

However, if the API gives me an `Author` first, and I download its `Book`, the object will be deallocated once the method in which I set it returns, because the same property is `weak`.

I thought of a few ways around this:

- Create a `Content` object that stores both (not viable for many-to-many relationships)
- Create separate `strongBook` and `weakBook` properties, and then make a `readonly` property called `book` which checks which is set and returns that one

Those both seem messy to me, although the second option is preferable.

Is there a way to dynamically change a property from `weak` to `strong` (and vice-versa) using the Objective-C runtime?

**UPDATE:** I'm getting a few suggestions on how to work around the issue, which I don't have trouble coming up with myself.  This question is specifically about whether there is a way to either (a) dynamically redefine @properties for a specific instance of a class, or (b) override ARC's `retain`/`release` behavior in specific circumstances (since this issue wouldn't exist in MRC).

Comment: Fix your API definition. It's that simple.

Comment: Why not make them both weak and then keep NSArrays of all of your books and authors to keep them around?

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII Yes, but in this case I need to work around it.

Comment: @EricS That could work, but then I have another maintenance point when I want to delete an item.

Comment: The author should be weak, and the book strong, not viceversa. So a book is retained 1 time if it has a single author. The way you're doing it an author is retained *N* times.

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri - My point is that sometimes the book is the primary object, and sometimes the author is the primary object.  And, I'd like the secondary object to point back to the primary object.  I'm not concerned about multiple books or multiple authors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a shot in the dark, but you could create the property and not specify and then use dynamic with the runtime apis. I didn't test it, but i think it should work:

```
//.h file
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface SomeObject : NSObject
@property(nonatomic) NSObject *object;
@end


//.m file
#import "SomeObject.h"
#import <objc/runtime.h>
@implementation SomeObject
@dynamic object;

-(void)setObject:(NSObject *)object
{
    BOOL isWeak = NO;
    if(isWeak)
    {
        objc_setAssociatedObject(self, "object", object, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_ASSIGN);
    }
    else
    {
        objc_setAssociatedObject(self, "object", object, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN);
    }
}

-(NSObject *)object
{
    return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, "object");
}

@end
```

Comment: This works.  (I ended up making a setter with an additional argument like `-[SomeObject setObject:isWeak:]`).

Comment: I would be very careful with the approach suggest in this answer. With 'OBJC_ASSOCIATION_ASSIGN' you create the equivalent of an `assign`/`unsafeUnretained` property and definitely not a `weak` one - the property will not be automatically set to `nil` when the object gets deallocated. So if you try to access that property you're app will crash.

Answer (score 0):

For the period of the download, create a mutable dictionary to temporarily store author objects that arrive prior to the book. When a book is received, look in that array and see if the author info is there, if so attach it. When you are finished clean out the mutable array.

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri, with a set he has to look at every item in the set to find the right Author. Assuming there is some identifier that can be used as a key, the dictionary gives you a quick way to find the right one. I've actually used this technique before, and on more than one occasion, with great success.